# Font face not working on mac but works fine on pc

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

For some reason one specific font doesnt work on mac :/

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kipling Light';
    src: url('fonts/KiplingLight-Regular.eot');
   src: local("☺"),
         url('fonts/KiplingLight-Regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('fonts/KiplingLight-Regular.woff') format('woff'),
         url('fonts/KiplingLight-Regular.otf') format('opentype');

}
@font-face {
font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
src: url('fonts/HelveticaNeueCE-Roman.eot');
src: local("☺"),
    url('fonts/helvetica_neue_ce_55_roman-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('fonts/HelveticaNeueCE-Roman.woff') format('woff'),
     url('fonts/HelveticaNeueCE-Roman.otf') format('opentype');

}
```

thats my css code and im inserting my data like this:

```
.contenidored{
    font-family: 'HelveticaNeue';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#8C8B8C;
}
```

Helvetica is the one is not working, do you have any ideas?
http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0039_kiplingmexico/demo2/

Comment: Seems to be working for me in Chrome.. What browser are you using?

Comment: really? for some reason i dont see it working on my mac :/ not even firefox , safari and chrome hella weird :/. But on my pc it runs great!

Comment: by any chance can you send me a screenshot or someone?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be like hella weird but i just changed the typhografy and it worked. Maybe there was something wrong on the archive.

Comment: What's the difference between before and after ? Can you post your answer / auto-answer your question ?